# Average of month's values from different .xls files

Tags: excel

**I don't know the difficulty of doing this, but if you can give me at least an advice or a recommendation of what to try or study, it would be great**

I have different files for each month, (e.g. Jan_17, Feb_17 ... Dec_17) that shows hourly prices of energy in different substations, so a month with 31 days will have 744 values for each substation. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SShtN.jpg).

[image]

I can easily do this for one .xls file (one month) but my objective is to analyze historical data of these prices for each substation and graph its variation over years, but this would take a lot of time if I do it manually (pivot table) for each month and then copy and paste it on my summary table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the kind of job that Power Query was designed for. Power Query is part of Excel 2016 and a free add in to Excel 2010 and Excel 2013.

The general approach is: If all files have the same structure, put all files into the same folder, then query the folder with Power Query. You can combine all files into one big table and you can use that table for pivoting.

The query can be refreshed when new data files are added to the original folder.

There is a wealth of Power Query information on the internet. A search on "how to combine all files in a folder with Power Query" should get you started.